# How to connect to a nodejs server through socketio in android(java) such that each activity of the app share the socket instance?

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

my app has two activity.
1. To show the names of all the user connected to the server in a recyler view.
2. On clicking a name, a new activity is created which will be there to show
and have a private chat with the user.

I am using Nodejs as server and Socketio.
I want the socket.emit() and socket.on() in android to work in background 
and can be used for all the activities. i.e I do not want to call socket.connect() each time the activity changes. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can check this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095293/android-storing-socket-io-object-for-multiple-activities

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102332/best-way-to-implement-socket-io-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Storing Socket.io object for multiple activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095293/android-storing-socket-io-object-for-multiple-activities)